# Imports with absolute paths in a small-medium data science project

Tags: python, makefile

I know that there are tons of similar questions here but I couldn't figure out which best suits my project. This is a small data research project organized in the following way:

```
project-name/
   docs/
   src/
      __init__.py
      config.yml
      Makefile
      data/
      data_management/ 
          __init__.py
          process1.py
          process2/
      analysis/
          __init__.py
          analysis1.py
          analysis2/
      library/
          __init__.py
          config.py
```

The Makefile in the root directory subsequently executes several scripts sitting in `data_management` (to prepare the raw data) and `analysis`, or in their subdirectories respectively (since some processes are quite extensive sometimes).

Each of those modules are self-contained - except that they both import (and thus share) functions/classes from the `library` dir (I read that violating the principle of self-containing modules should be avoided but I did not know how to solve it without having to copy functinos). One example is my configuration class in `config.py` (which manages database information, paths to relevant subdirectories, different user specifications etc.)

**Problem**: I find it best if I could have an absolute import path in each of these scripts, i.e. if I could write `import library.config` anywhere in the project. But it feels wrong to have

```
# project-name/src/data_management/process1/data_to_sql.py    
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
import library.config
config = library.config.Configuration()
```

at the top of this or any other script (because in order to access my "path management system", I run into the problem of specifying paths).

**Question(s)**: How can I avoid having to `sys.path.insert` in any file? Should I avoid editing the `PYTHONPATH`? If not, how can I automate this setup in the makefile (since, ultimately, I want to share this code with others)?

Thank you.

Edit: I use Python 2.7.11.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a Package out of your project by creating a `setup.py` file in `project-name`. Afterwards you can do

```
pip install -e project-name/
```

and from everywhere in your Python environment you can then do

```
import project_name
import project_name.library.config
```

Also, if you do

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

you can do import statements like

```
from ..library import config
```

to essentially import `../library/config.py`

Comment: This does not fit my project structure since it has to be `import src.library.config', no? I get your point, though, thank you.

Comment: [Thats up to you and depends on what you put in your `setup.py`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html). The content in `src/` may end up in `import project_name.src` or `import project_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

1. If this is Python 2.7 you must have `__init__.py` in each directory to make it importable. Not needed for Python 3.
2. Since the makefile is run from within `src` then that is base of your imports. Each script will need `sys.path.insert(0, '.')` and then feel free to then have `from analysis.analysis1 import foo, bar`.
3. Check out `https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject` for a recommended way to package your scripts so that they can be distributed, installed and even called from the `PYTHONPATH` e.g. by running `python -c 'import mypackage`.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that, when you wrote about the config file, you've wrote 'config.py'. However in your code it seems to be a .yml file.

If you would choose to use a .py file, you could access it this way:

```
from src import config
```

Comment: Though it may be redundant, I create a class for this because, for example, I want to have several "consistency checks" to guarantee that all necessary information is specified.

Comment: "from src.config import Configuration" should work if you would create a Configuration class in config.py. I would recommend however to rename 'src' into something more project related, we just use the project-name again. It makes your imports more defined and you end up with less ambiguity. I also suggest you follow Nils Werner's guidelines and create a setup.py. https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html